# My hosted Azure pipeline is failing with: rcz discover exited with code -2147450730

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-pipelines

I have two aspnet core 3.1 applications and have set up two azure piplines:
One pipeline is working fine building and testing my project, the other one (similar structure and referencing same projects) is failing with following error:

```
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\build\netstandard2.0\Sdk.Razor.CurrentVersion.targets(404,5): warning RAZORSDK1006: Detected Razor language version downgrade. This is typically caused by a reference to the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design package. Consider removing this package reference. [d:\a\1\s\Sources\Web\Web.csproj]
CSC : warning CS8034: Unable to load Analyzer assembly C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.analyzers\2.2.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Analyzers.dll : Assembly with same name is already loaded [d:\a\1\s\Sources\Web\Web.csproj]
C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design\2.2.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets(79,5): error : rzc discover exited with code -2147450730. [d:\a\1\s\Sources\Web\Web.csproj]
    54 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:02:41.66
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated to contain .Net Core 3.x SDK/Runtime along with 2.2 & 2.1. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 3.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. 
Some commonly encountered changes are: 
If you're using `Publish` command with -o or --Output argument, you will see that the output folder is now being created at root directory rather than Project File's directory. To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : d:\a\1\s\Sources\Web\Web.csproj
```

Does someone have an idea what I can check?
Kind regards

Comment: Well, suddenly it works. Fixed some warnings in cshtml files but honestly I don't know what happened